# CRM 2011 linq and saved query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to use CRM 2011 View (savedquery) with linq? I mean can I do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Opportunity> GetOpportunites(CrmOrganizationServiceContext context, string viewName, Guid customerId)
{
    var view = context.CreateQuery<SavedQuery>().FirstOrDefault(q => q.Name == viewName);
    if(view!=null)
       return from Opportunity op in view
           where op.CustomerId.Id == customerId
           select op;
           return new List<Opportunity>();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Does it produce an error, does it work, does it do something other than what you want?

Comment: Code above does not work. I just write it to explain what I try to aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly would not. As Servy suggested, try it out and you'd see why.

`SavedQuery` has two properties that define a view - `FetchXml` (the underlying query) and `LayoutXml` (the columns returned in the UI). In other words, it does not return the *data* that the view returns in the UI, but rather the *definition* of how the data is returned in the UI.

The most cut-and-dry way to enumerate through the records you're expecting to have returned from a view is to use a `FetchRequest` directly. You'd have to insert your condition dynamically as an XML node in the `FetchXml`.

You can also parse the XML filter set, then translate appropriate to Linq, but this would obviously be more challenging, perhaps unnecessarily so.

A third approach is to create a static view in the system where as a condition you set the customer equal to some arbitrary customer, and then change the customer id dynamically in the XML string.